# Cannot resolve final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Cannot reolve

```
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

If I change it to

```
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

it won't resolve the getUid in this

```
if (!user.getUser_id().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    mUsers.add(user);
```

And if I change it to `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseUser.getInstance();` it wont resolve the getInstance(); What can I do to remove the error please help

```
    private void readUsers() {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    assert user !=null;
                    assert firebaseUser !=null;
                    if (!user.getUser_id().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` returns an instance of `FirebaseAuth`, so this:

```
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

should be this instead:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then change this:

```
assert user !=null;
assert firebaseUser !=null;
if (!user.getUser_id().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
     mUsers.add(user);
 }
```

into this:

```
if (!user.getUser_id().equals(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
     mUsers.add(user);
}
```